# I want to update TextBoxes and add ListView row while updating what I do?

Tags: c#, sql

I need to add/edit a new row on `ListView` while updating TextBoxes. What I can do? Please, give me some suggestion. Thanks.
I tried this code:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
        con.Open();
        String cb = "update Invoice_info set  VATPer='" + txtTaxPer.Text + "',VATAmount='" + txttableno.Text + "',DiscountPer='" + txtDiscountPer.Text + "',DiscountAmount='" + txtDiscountAmount.Text + "',GrandTotal= '" + txtTotal.Text + "',TotalPayment= '" + txtTotalPayment.Text + "',PaymentDue= '" + txtPaymentDue.Text + "',Remarks='" + txtCustomerName.Text + "' where Invoiceno= '" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        con.Close();

        //int i = 1;
        //ListView1.BeginUpdate();
        //ListView1.Items.Clear();
        // //var item = new  bool 
        //foreach (var  item in items )
        //{
        //    ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(i.ToString());
        //    row.SubItems.Add(item.EventId);
        //    row.SubItems.Add(item.Name);
        //    row.SubItems.Add(item.WordPos);
        //    lstXmlItems.Items.Add(row);
        //    i++;
        //}
        //ListView1.EndUpdate();
        //ListView1.Refresh();
        //for (int i = 0; i <= ListView1.Items.Count ; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
            string cd = "insert Into ProductSold(InvoiceNo,ProductID,ProductName,Quantity,Price,TotalAmount) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(cd);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", txtInvoiceNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d3", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d4", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d5", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d6", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text);
            con.Open();
            //  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
            con.Close();
        }

        btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you explain more, please?

Comment: dear  Saeid Amin !! I use this in the restaurant management system where when I place the order  and add item into listview after a place I want to change table number and add some more in list view row item hope you understand

Comment: You have a form with `TestBoxes`. You fill TextBoxes and click add `Button` and you want to values added to `ListView`. This all of that you want?

Comment: no no add successfully into listview but I want to update listview row

Comment: Ok, Let me say again. You select one of the rows and all of the row data show in text boxes. when you change some of them and click the update button and now, you want the selected row updates.

Comment: in  form, when I want to update data from DB I fetch data successfully I update textboxes successfully but when we add more row during update they duplicate the previous row . in restaurant first order take then change in the order needed updations in item

Comment: dear i show form image in my answer check thanks

Comment: dear, I think its working but not do you have any other piece of code or suggestion which I add a new row in listview successfully while updating?

Answer (score 0):

[in this form I retrieve data using order no see on top of them for table name and table no show in text boxes that I change successfully but the data show in listview product name, price, qty, total amount, not added new row but copy the previous row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePBlF.png)